# Link to the Device Manager

Tags: c#, wpf, device-manager

Is there a way to add a link to the Device Manager in a WPF application? I mean, a hyperlink that once clicked opens the Device Manager window.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you use:

```
Process.Start("devmgmt.msc");
```

for the *_onclick method ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "mmc.exe",
                Arguments = "devmgmt.msc"
            };

            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = processStartInfo
            };

            process.Start();
```